# Lower bound for the square root sum of the roots of $x - \ln x - m$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $f(x)=x-\ln x$. Suppose $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=m$ ($x_1<x_2$). How can I prove that

$$\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}\ge\sqrt{m}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}?$$

## My Attempt

I tried to rewrite the condition as
\begin{align}
&x_1-\ln x_1=m,\\
&x_2-\ln x_2=m.
\end{align}
By summing up the two equalities and by subtracting one equality from the other, we have
\begin{align}
&x_1+x_2-\ln x_1x_2=2m,\\
&\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}=\frac{\ln x_2-\ln x_1}{\sqrt{x_2}-\sqrt{x_1}}.
\end{align}
But I don't know how to continue then.

Comment: in title of question there is $m$?

Comment: @TheStudent It's equivalent. $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=m$ implies $x_1,x_2$ are the roots of $x-\ln x-m$.

Comment: Negative result to report: since we can find $x_1'(m)$ and $x_2'(m)$ by implicit differentiation, I was hoping to prove that the difference between the two sides of the inequality was an increasing function of $m$ ... but computations show that's not actually the case.

Comment: @GregMartin I think you were on the right track because the LHS - RHS was increasing for $m > \sim 5$

Comment: It actually starts decreasing again later on :/ , and seems to have limit 0

Comment: Some similar problems: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481810/an-inequality-on-the-roots-of-a-transcendental-equation/3483445#3483445, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725944/estimate-the-bound-of-the-sum-of-the-roots-of-1-x-ln-x-a-where-a1?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This is true if you consider that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are explicitly given in terms of Lambert function (for $m \geq 1$).
$$x_1=-W_0(-e^{-m}) \qquad \text{and} \qquad x_2=-W_{-1}(-e^{-m}) $$

Now, 
$$x_1^k+x_2^k \geq (m^k+m^{-k})$$ *seems* to hold for any $k \geq 0.48166\cdots$

Comment: How do you get $k\ge 0.48166$?

Comment: @xskxzr. Numerical analysis